# Google pay is not showing the payment sheet, it is opening in a new tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-pay

I have followed the instructions to add the Google Pay button to my website.
It works perfectly on Desktop Chrome, you click the button the payment sheet slides in from the bottom and your card details are there.

However when I test it on a mobile device, still using Chrome it opens the Google Pay in a new tab.

If I try the sample page on the mobile device, it works. The payment sheet slides up from the bottom of the screen.

My code appears to be the same as the sample, so I have no idea why it is opening in a new tab.

Anyone else come across this?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior on mobile currently depends on the Google Pay features that you use. If you integrate with any of the [`paymentDataCallbacks`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataCallbacks), it will launch the payment sheet in a popup.

The behavior on Android will ultimately be updated not to use a popup but requires some Android API changes to be rolled out first.